# How to use array as input for a function in c++

Tags: c++

In C++, is it possible to give array as input to a function.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you can do this all with vectors.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> function_name(const std::vector<int>& A, const std::vector<int>& B);
```